# Do Convolutional Layers Pool data?

Tags: conv-neural-network, convolution, pooling

Sorry for the trivial question but considering this example in the image attached doesn't the conv layer pool data by summing them? What I am asking is if this images describes a subset where a conv layer and a pooling layer work sequentially or if this is the normal behavior of conv layers.
Thank you in advance[image]

Comment: Convolution sums in generic sense, consider Max function

Comment: Do you understand how the$4\times 4$ array is calculated?

Comment: The image shows a convolution layer, not a convolution layer followed by a pooling layer. Convolution layers sum the element-wise products with the filter.